# matplotlib.pyplot.show() in PyCharm moves my axes! How can I prevent this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

When I create a figure in matplot lib and render that figure in PyCharm with matplotlib.pyplot.show(), the figure moves!

This does not occur show()ing outside of PyCharm.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

def axes_position_test():
    """Witness change in position after plt.show()."""
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # original position
    print(ax1.get_position())

    plt.show()

    # position has changed
    print(ax1.get_position())

axes_position_test()
# output
# Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
# Bbox(x0=0.07300347222222223, y0=0.08067129629629632, x1=0.959375, y1=0.9572916666666668)
```

Comment: FWIW, I get an AssertionError on the last line, i.e. the axes positions do not change for me. May I ask what are you trying to accomplish by making the positions identical?

Comment: That means it may have something to do with rendering through PyCharm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem - the code results in an error for me running matplotlib 3.0.2. Maybe a different version is in use?

In any case, to generally answer this:
Positions may change over time, especially if the figure is shown inside a GUI which may itself (slightly) change the figure size.

The question is not really clear about the ultimate goal, but as I interprete it, the aim is to have two axes on top of each other. That is easily accomplished via

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="first axes")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="second axes")
```

More sophisticated geometries can be made with `gridspec`, always using `add_subplot` to add the subplot.

Edit from OP: As revealed in comments, the PyCharm renderer, interagg, is the problem. Disabling interagg (Settings > Tools > Python Scientific > uncheck "show plots") corrects the problem.

Comment: Figure was indeed shown inside a gui (PyCharm). I guess that's it. Shame really, as the integration is nice in PyCharm. But if my render doesn't match my file (the file is correct), then the render is not expecially useful.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the render in pycharm, but the naive use of `get_position`. Did you try adding the axes as shown in this answer? Does it result in the correct positions when used in pycharm?

Comment: @ImporanceOfBeingErnest. Adding the axes as shown here leaves them in the same position, but it's not the position they were in before calling plt.show(). If I savefig before and after plt.show(), I get different images!

Comment: Interesting. What you describe is really at the heart of the problem. Because that should not happen with any of the native backends. By how much do the positions differ?

Comment: The positions differ A LOT Bbox(0=0.125, y0=0.11, x1=0.9, y1=0.88) to Bbox(x0=0.17, y0=0.18, x1=0.92, y1=0.93). That's with your example. My original example was even worse. This happens with only one plot.

Comment: That is too much to be coincidental or caused by small differences in pixel stamping. I fear I cannot be of more help here because I'm not profilient with pycharm or any of the settings it has. All I know is that it provides its own matplotlib backend, called `interagg`, so possibly you can deactivate that somewhere?

Comment: I've done more testing. This is definitely a PyCharm problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192066/discussion-between-shay-and-importanceofbeingernest).